# How to graph the edges of roadbeds neatly on top of OpenStreetMaps?

Tags: gis, openstreetmap

I would like to neatly overlay linestrings representing the edge of a roadbed on top of an OpenStreetMap map like in the image. [Open Curb Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evt0e.png)

That is, I want linestrings that line up exactly with the edge of the road when mapped in OpenStreetMap. Using NYC Open Data, I have tried creating offset lines that are half the distance from the centerline of the roadbed, but the cartographic representation of roads in OpenStreetMap is different than the actual road width.

Is this something that can be accomplished by offsetting the centerline a certain distance depending on the value of the highway key?

I'm now trying to work with OpenStreetMap data directly, but am stuck about how wide to offset the from the centerline, especially because it seems the width changes as the zoom level changes.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm now trying to work with OpenStreetMap data directly, but am stuck about how wide to offset the from the centerline, especially because it seems the width changes as the zoom level changes.

OpenStreetMap doesn't know anything about zoom levels. I guess you are talking about a rendered OSM-based map? The width of the rendered road is a decision by the renderer or the rendering stylesheet.

OpenStreetMap has a `width=*` tag to specify the width of a road. This tag is not often present, though. Other relevant attributes are the road classification via the `highway=*` tag as well as lane count (`lanes=*` tag) and probably also the existence of cycle lanes (`cycleway=*` tag). Based on these information you can guess the width of the road if the `width=*` tag isn't present.